# How do I use my own password with aes in java

Tags: java, file, encryption, aes

How do I use my own custom key(password) with aes in java? I want to use a file as a password to encrypt another file I know you normally use a SecretKeyGenerator but I want to use my own key/password. I read about using something called SALT but I can't find an example anywhere would someone show me some code to encrypt /decrypt or just what line to replace from a normal  aes encryption

Comment: Can you post a code sample, is this using a specific library etc? I would think you would use your custom phrase for "SALT" if i am think of this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a [SecretKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html#SecretKeySpec%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) instance:

```
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(bytesOfTheKey, "AES");
```

Just make sure to pass a byte array with the appropriate number of bytes (16 for AES-128)

Comment: Was that a answer, combine then close action by you JB? :)

Comment: I typed and answer, and then saw a comment mentioning that it was a duplicate from the same author. So I voted to close the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `new SecretKeySpec(byte[], "AES")` - this can be directly used as a `SecretKey` of type `"AES"`. If the file has enough entropy you may want to generate a SHA-256 hash over the file and use that as first parameter of the `SecretKeySpec` constructor. If the other file is lacking entropy then you might want to use the SHA-256 over the file as input for password based encryption.

If the files exist next to each other, you will have accomplished obscurity at best, of course. The cipher to use and the use of additional integrity checks on the cipher text depends on your use case.